# Sending and Monitoring DNS Queries

Tags: wireshark, tcp, tcpdump

I'm trying to monitor DNS queries on my server using `tcpdump`, but `tcpdump` doesn't seem to be picking up the request, or it's not being sent to my server.

I run `tcpdump` on the server like so:

```
tcpdump -vvv -s 0 -l -n port 53
```

I then send a DNS request to my server with:

```
 nslookup google.com xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

`xx.xx.xxx.xxx` is my servers IP.

And the response:

```
Server:     xx.xx.xxx.xxx
Address:    xx.xx.xxx.xxx#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.208.78
```

I do not have Bind running, or even installed, but `tcpdump` should still capture the packets right?

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: How many network interfaces (other than the loopback interface) do you have on your machine?

Comment: So you have both an Ethernet and a Wi-Fi interface; are you connected to your DNS server via the Ethernet interface or the Wi-Fi interface?  What does `tcpdump -D` print?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my view on this. Please pardon me if it goes slightly offtopic.

Now, DNS resolution is going to happen iff:

- A machine receiving a DNS query is behaving as a resolver, **OR**,
- A machine receiving a DNS query is acting as some kind of middleware proxy for a DNS resolver.

Can you explain why will there by any kind of DNS resolution if above is not the case?.

For completeness of the above comment,

> The −D flag will not be supported if tcpdump(8) was built with an older version of libpcap that lacks the pcap_findalldevs() function.

Now, I assume:

- Listening on the correct network interface (you may want to **explicitly** choose the correct interface to listen on w.r.t. tcpdump(8)),
- Incoming is allowed on UDP 53 (network/host level),
- One of the above stated conditions are met,

It should work.

```
tcpdump -vvv -n -s 0 -l -i eth0 udp port 53
```

Take out **-n** and retry to see the difference.

You can also post what versions of *nslookup(1)* and *tcpdump(8)* are you using.